# Firefox getUserMedia throws OverconstrainedError for video constrains 480 X 720

Tags: firefox, web-mediarecorder, mediadevices

Javascript throws OverconstrainedError in Firefox.

```
navigator.mediaDevices({video:{
    width: { min: 480, max: 480 },
    height: { max: 720, min:720 },
}})
.then(stream => {
   //assign stream to video element
})
.catch(error => {})
```

I wanted  to get these resolution, or get similar aspect ratio for Firefox desktop version. if I use these constraints `{video: { width:{ideal:480}, height: {ideal:720, max: 720 }}` it gives me height: 720, width: 960.

I managed to get 480 X 720 resolution on Chrome and Opera, but it would be nice if I could find a way to record a video using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) at these resolutions.

Config:
Firefox version: 57.0.2(64 bit), Video device: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920